# Symfony2: Secure/Safe login and logout

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, logout

What should I add to approach secure and safe login and logout?

For login I simply fetched and validated information from database, then I set the Session and Cookie:

```
if ($users) { //$users - fetched array of users
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('user', $cookie, $expire, $path = '/', $domain = '', $secure = false, $httpOnly = false));
        $response->sendHeaders();

        foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
            //setting every user information to session except password
            $session->set($key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

And for logout I just delete sessions and cookie:

```
$response->headers->clearCookie('user');
$response->sendHeaders();

$request->getSession()->invalidate();
```

The 'user' value that I set to cookie is generated by:

```
$password = $user['password']; //is already in md5
$username = $user['email'];
$cookie = base64_encode ("$username:" . md5 ($password));
```

All of this is stored into main controller.

Comment: why set the cookie? And you really shouldn't be using MD5 for passwords, look into bcrypt or pbkdf2

Comment: @JimL to recreate session everytime user comes into website. And yes, I used md5 for password and for salt.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a good way to do login and logout implementation. Take a look at Symfony2 security tutorial. Use UserProvider to get the user from the database and set the security token if success.

For a start - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html

MD5 function is not safe anymore. If you want, use something stronger than that for encoding passwords, together with salt.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically login and logout users like this, if you implemented the user provider and repository as described in the [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html).

The following is an example implementation:

**Login:**

```php
$username = $user['email'];
$password = $user['password']; // NOTE: must be plain-text at this point

$User = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()
    ->getRepository('TixysBackendBundle:User')
    ->findOneBy(array('login' => $username));

if (!$User) throw \Exception("User not found!");

$factory = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory');
$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($User);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($password, $User->getSalt());

if ($password != $User->getPassword())
    throw new \Exception("Wrong password.");

// actual login
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($User, null, 'secured_area', $User->getRoles());
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

**Logout:**

```php
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
$this->container->get('session')->invalidate();

// If you've stored an instance of the previously authenticated user
// somewhere, destroy that instance, too.
```

You don't need to care about the actual hashing algorithms at this point, given that your setup in `app/config/security.yml` is done properly.

Comment: how about storing user in a cookie and sessions?

Comment: The session will be destroyed with `invalidate()`. This will also invalidate the cookie (as it's bound to the session).